# Define constant array to use as template parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constants

I am looking for a definition of constants (n) allowing them to be used as parameter in a template constructor, eg. something like this:

```
const int n[5] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  SomeClass<n[i]> C;
  (...other things depending on n[i])
}
```

SomeClass looks like

```
template<int n> class SomeClass {...}
```

Is there any way to this (using macros or anything else)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using recursive templates to do the looping and specifying `n` as a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). This will only work in C++11 or greater. Working example ([ideone link](https://ideone.com/leaBK9)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int n> 
class SomeClass 
{
// debug function for example
public:
    void debug() {
        cout << "SomeClass<" << n << ">" << endl;
    }
};

constexpr int n[5] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };

template <int i>
struct loop
{
    static void doit()
    {
        SomeClass<n[i]> C;
        C.debug();
        // other things depending on n[i]
        loop<i+1>::doit();
    }
};

// close out the iteration
template <> 
struct loop<std::extent<decltype(n)>::value>
{    
    static void doit() 
    {
    } 
};

int main() {
    loop<0>::doit();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SomeClass<4>
SomeClass<8>
SomeClass<16>
SomeClass<32>
SomeClass<64>
```

Comment: I think it works in C++11 as well (tried on both Clang and GCC).

Comment: @REACHUS: Thanks, tried it myself in gcc also and it worked - updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with that `for` loop. The reason is simple: `n[i]` inside the loop is not a constant expression. `i` could change inside the loop in different ways and the information about whether to instantiate a specific instance of `SomeClass` or some other is runtime-dependent.

You can use *template meta programming* instead:

```
template <int from, int to>
struct for_ {
    template<template<int> class Fn>
    static void run() {
        Fn<from>::run();
        for_<from + 1, to>::template run<Fn>();
    }
};

template <int to> 
struct for_<to, to> {  
    template<template<int> class Fn>
    static void run() {} 
};
```

We can then define our own utilities:

```
template <int n> 
struct SomeClass {};

constexpr int n[5] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };

template<int i>
struct functor {
    static void run() {
        SomeClass<n[i]> c;
        // something else
    }
};
```

and use it as:

```
int main() {
    for_<0, 5>::run<functor>();
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7dd7c1632e6434)

Comment: The point of the question is "how do I make `n[i]` constant". The answer "you need to make `n[i]` constant" is therefore not useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ow. I'm sorry you didn't like the answer. :(

Comment: This is a nicer way to do the for loop!